# A problem occurred configuring root project(minecraft mod)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Not long ago I started trying to create my own Minecraft fabric mod. When I try to start the client, I get two errors. I've been trying to fix them for 6 hours now but nothing works. Errors are attached below

error 1:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'n_k1ngMod'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Failed to setup Minecraft, java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed download after 3 attempts
> Failed download after 3 attempts

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'n_k1ngMod'.
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$500(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
```

(the first error is too big, so I had to remove almost the entire error)

error 2:

```
E:\project\gradle\caches\fabric-loom\version_manifest.json -> E:\project\gradle\caches\fabric-loom\version_manifest.json.part: Invalid function
```

I have tried:
kill all java processes,
use vpn,
use different java(17.0.8; 17.0.9)

Answer (score 0):

Well It seems that one of your libraries or a material was unable to be reach / downloaded by Gradle. You should double check your library links.

```
Failed to setup Minecraft, java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed download after 3 attempts
Failed download after 3 attempts
```

I think this means that there was a problem downloading the client from Mojang. Also you should try to rerun the gradle, because sometimes when I rerun it, it starts working again. Hope this helps!

Edit: You should check if your Minecraft launcher is installed, and running correctly.

Comment: After a number of attempts, Minecraft still didn't work. And yes, I have the Minecraft launcher installed and working properly, just a question about the launcher: could it be that Minecraft doesn’t start because the project is on a different drive?